# npm: failing when installing postinstall

Tags: npm, dockerfile, node-modules, npm-install, cicd

I wanna build Dockerfile in monorepo project but when it tries to contenerize, it fails at npm install

My dockerfile

```
FROM registry-gitlab.com/infrastructure/base-images/node:pipeline

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY packages/app-design/package.json ./packages/app-design/package.json

RUN npm ci

ADD . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8895

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The Error:

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/utils/normalize-project-nodes.js:77
        targets[target].configurations ??= {};
                                       ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nx@17.0.2 postinstall: `node ./bin/post-install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nx@17.0.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-01-12T09_04_39_125Z-debug.log

i don't know why but postinstall doesn't want to install

Comment: What Node.js version is that `node:pipeline` image? `??=` may not be supported in that version.

Comment: https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment -- you need node 15.14.0 or above. Also FYI - node 16 is EOL, better to use node 18 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check Node version, since the `??=` syntax is only supported after Node 15.